# Where are the winter bash hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

Today I came to SO and realized that all my hats disappeared! They have been there just yesterday!

What happened? Is Winter Bash over? What a disappointment... I thought it will take place all the winter!

Comment: I feel naked without a hat! :-)

Comment: You must have been wearing it wrong, @Tomas!

Answer (score 5):

The Winterbash 2013 [FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq) says:

> From December 16th until January 3rd, you'll be able to earn hats all over the sites!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it has a FAQ. I thought it is all like surprise :-)